# How do I update a FutureBuilder widget with the results of a new future?

Tags: flutter

I have a futureBuilder widget displaying records from a database, and I'm getting those records from an async future network request. There are a few choiceChip widgets that onSelected assign a new future to the FutureBuilders future.

The first time a choiceChip is clicked the new future is called and created but the displayed records don't update. If you click the same choiceChip a second time, the records update and are displayed correctly.

Why doesn't the futureBuilder update on the first click of the choiceChip even though the new future is being called and assigned correctly?

UPDATE: I switched from a future to a stream and added a check to see if the ConnectionState was done. That seems to have done the trick.

```
class _HousingFeedState extends State<HousingFeed> with AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin<HousingFeed> {
  Future<List<Housing>> _future;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _future = housingFeed(0, "");
  }    

  Widget _chipRow = new Container(
    child: SingleChildScrollView(
      child: Row(
        children: List<Widget>.generate(
          5,
          (int index) {
            return Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 5.0),
              child: ChoiceChip(
                selected: _housingType == index,
                onSelected: (bool selected) {
                  setState(() {
                    _housingType = index;
                    _future = housingFeed(subcategoryMap[index], '');
                  });
                },
              ),
            );
          },
        ).toList(),
      ),
    ),
  );

  Widget housingBuilder = FutureBuilder<List<Housing>>(
    future: _future,
    builder: (context, snapshot) {
       ...
    }
  );
}

Future<List<Housing>> housingFeed(int subcategoryId, String search) async {
  String url = "https://...";

  final response = await http.post(url, 
    headers: {HttpHeaders.contentTypeHeader: 'application/json'},
    body: jsonEncode({
      "id": userId,
      "filter": {"id": subcategoryId},
      "search": search
    }));

  if (response.statusCode == 200) {
    var housingListings = List<Housing>();
    var jsonData = json.decode(response.body);
    jsonData['response'].forEach((listing) {
      housingListings.add(Housing.fromJson(listing));
     });
    return housingListings;
  } else {
    throw Exception('Failed to load');
  }
}
```